# MongoDB documents relationship with beanie

Tags: mongodb, fastapi

I'm building a simple backend todos application with FastAPI and Mongodb (with beanie). It also includes users management and auth.

Here are my 2 documents:

```
from beanie import Document, Indexed, Link, before_event, Replace, Insert
from datetime import datetime
from uuid import uuid4
from pydantic import Field, UUID4
from .user_model import User

class Todo(Document):
    todo_id : UUID4 = Field(default_factory=uuid4, unique = True)
    status : bool = False
    title : Indexed(str)
    description : Indexed(str)
    created_at : datetime = Field(default_factory=datetime.utcnow)
    updated_at : datetime = Field(default_factory=datetime.utcnow)
    owner: Link[User]

    @before_event([Replace, Insert])
    def update_updated_at(self):
        self.updated_at = datetime.utcnow()

    class Settings:
        name = "todos"
```

```
from beanie import Document, Indexed
from datetime import datetime
from uuid import uuid4
from pydantic import Field, EmailStr, UUID4
from typing import Optional

class User(Document):
    user_id: UUID4 = Field(default_factory=uuid4)
    username : Indexed(str, unique = True)
    email: Indexed(EmailStr, unique=True)
    hashed_password : str
    first_name : Optional[str] = None
    last_name: Optional[str] = None
    disabled: Optional[bool] = False

    @property
    def create(self) -> datetime:
        return self.id.generation_time
    
    @classmethod
    async def by_email(self, email:str) -> "User":
        return await self.find_one(self.email == email)
    
    class Settings:
        name = "users"
```

However after creating a todo I get the below response :

```
{
  "_id": "65bb7c8e76930c19e08dac3a",
  "todo_id": "151129e4-64a3-4293-8bbf-6eef9468e7c8",
  "status": false,
  "title": "string",
  "description": "string",
  "created_at": "2024-02-01T11:12:14.906333",
  "updated_at": "2024-02-01T11:12:14.907131",
  "owner": {
    "id": "None",
    "collection": "users"
  }
}
```

Any idea why I cannot get the complete users insights instead of a None id and the collection name ?

Thank you